# Python - Executing a function in another script in a child folder

Tags: python, variables, parent-child, working-directory

I have a master script that executes several child scripts within subfolders of the main directory.

The folder hierarchy looks like:

```
MyFolder\MasterScript.py
MyFolder\ChildOneScript\ChildOne.py
MyFolder\ChildTwoScript\ChildTwo.py
MyFolder\ChildThreeScript\ChildThree.py
```

From MasterScript, I need call a function in ChildOne "myChildFunction" & pass some variables to it. The problem is, I **cannot** simply do

```
import ChildOneScript.ChildOne as ChildOne
ChildOne.myChildFunction
```

because there are other scripts that depend on the relative path of ChildOne. So if I import ChildOne to the MyFolder directory from the MasterScript and call myChildFunction there, I get traceback errors saying other files cannot be found. This is due to the mistakes of another stubborn programmer that refuses change his relative path calls, as it is a lot of manual work.

So, is there a way to call myChildFunction from within MasterScript **and** pass it some variables?

I'm aware I can use subprocess.call and it's cwd argument to change the working directory, but I can't figure out if it's possible to call the specific myChildFunction and pass it varaibles using subprocess.

***Edit:*** Is it possible to pass variables using execfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always hack it with the `os` module. It's not pretty, but it's probably the best you can do without rewriting all the other guy's code. If you'll be using functions from the other scripts a lot, I'd write a wrapper for the them to make it easier to call them:

```
import sys
import os

def call_legacy_func(func, *args, **opts):
    prev = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) # Save the real cwd
    try:
        # Get the child's physical location.
        func_path = sys.modules[func.__module__].__file__
    except:
        # Die; we got passed a built-in function (no __file__)
        # Or you could just call it, I guess: return func(*args, **opts)
        return None

    # Change to the expected directory and run the function.
    os.chdir(func_path)
    result = func(*args, **opts)

    # Fix the cwd, and return.
    os.chdir(prev)
    return result

import ChildOneScript.ChildOne as ChildOne
call_legacy_func(ChildOne.myChildFunction, 0, 1, kwarg=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, trying now.

Comment: Thank you very much, it may be a dirty hack but by god it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please clarify your problem? In particular, it's unclear to me what your issue with the folder layout and importing from subscripts is.

For example, if I create the following directory structure:

```
/example
    __init__.py
    master.py
    /childone
        __init__.py
        childone.py
    /childtwo
        __init__.py
        childtwo.py
```

Where the `__init__.py` are simply empty files and  the source files are as follows:

```
# master.py
from childone.childone import childone_fxn
from childtwo.childtwo import childtwo_fxn

print "Calling child one"
childone_fxn()

print "Calling child two"
childtwo_fxn()
```

--

```
# childone.py
def childone_fxn():
    print "hello from child one"
```

--

```
def childtwo_fxn():
    print "hello from child two"
```

From within `/example` I can then run `master.py` and get the expected output:

```
example $ python master.py 
Calling child one
hello from child one
Calling child two
hello from child two
```

You can of course use the subprocess module if you want to treat the child scripts like any other executable, but I can't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to import the child scripts directly.  But perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question...

Comment: Yes I understand why this would normally work, but as I said in my post:

"because there are other scripts that depend on the relative path of ChildOne. So if I import ChildOne to the MyFolder directory from the MasterScript and call myChildFunction there, I get traceback errors saying other files cannot be found. This is due to the mistakes of another stubborn programmer that refuses change his relative path calls, as it is a lot of manual work."

Edit: So to clarify, there are scripts in other directories called by ChildOne that depend on the relative path of ChildOne.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused -- the example I provided above doesn't require changing any paths, relative or not. Can you provide a full MWE to illustrate the issue?

Comment: His problem is that `ChildOne` has hard-coded relative paths in it that assume that `ChildOne` is in the current working directory. So when he imports `ChildOne` from someplace else and tries to use it, things start dying because it can't find files where it expects them.

Comment: @ Henry - Precisely, sorry if I was unclear. I'm working with another programmer and I cannot cause his scripts to die by importing ChildOne. I think Henry's answer below might work, trying now.

Comment: Henry -- thanks for the clarification. Now the problem makes sense.